# Send an email as an attachment from iPhone

Tags: ios, mobile-mail, attachments, iphone

This may be the most easy question to answer but I have struggled for few days now to get a proper view on how to achieve attaching an email on another email in iPhone 7.

I am a new iPhone user and would like to achieve

1. Attach existing email onto new email
2. Attach existing email to a reply/forward email

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can now drag and drop emails onto an email draft that you're editing on iPads that are running iOS 11 or iPhones running iOS 15.

1. Create a new email (or forward or reply to an existing email)
2. Swipe down on the email title bar (where it says "New Message" or the subject line) - you should now be able to interact with Mail again
3. Tap and hold on the email in your inbox list that you want to attach (it will appear to pop up)
4. Drag that email to the title bar of the draft email at the bottom of the screen until the edit window pops back open
5. Continue to drag that email to the body section of the email draft and a green circle with a plus sign will appear on the email that you're dragging
6. Drop/release into the body of the email you're editing - you should now see a .eml file attached

Comment: I have IOS 10.3.3 on my iPad4.
Step 3 in your sugestion gives no "pop up" response.
It simply displays the E-mail in the right side viewing panel when I lift my finger.

Comment: @LenPaton that's correct, you will only see the drag and drop functionality on iPads running iOS 11.

Comment: This does not work on iPad with 15.4. As soon as you tap on the inbox list the window for the email disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't send an email as an attachment on iOS. The only functionality available is to use the Forward button to quote a copy of the email (with or without the original attachments).

(On macOS [mail.app](/questions/tagged/mail.app), right-click on a message and select Forward as Attachment.)

Comment: Not quite correct : there is no obvious way, and it’s unreasonably convoluted, but it is possible to work around the fact apple have not implemented this basic functionality.

Comment: @Tom This was written in 2017, and at the time it was not possible.

Comment: Yes I know when it was written. It says on the article.  Apple have had lots of time and still have not fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like things have moved on since the original post, but unfortunately Apple has still not added this basic functionality to the iOS version of mail. It should be as simple as selecting “forward as attachment” but it’s not. You need it so you can forward spam and other emails unadulterated so the headers and other information that is normally not displayed is available to the recipient. A good example is forwarding a spam email to an anti spam services or a phishing email to the police (fraud squad). These are really important user stories that Apple seems to have forgotten about.

So this is what worked for me on an iPad running 15.4

1. Start a new email
2. Hit the … at the top [image: New message window showing … at top]
3. Choose split screen [image: Window showing split screen option at top]
4. Once you have mail with your new message on one side and your list of messages on the left, select the message and drag it into the message on the right. This can be really tricky as mail tries to show you previews etc before it works out you want to drag and drop.
   5.You should now see an attachment in you mail with a “.elm” extension. [image: New message showing attached email document]

That’s it. Now you can submit spam reports from your iPad

Answer (score 1):

Finally, Apple have added a proper (albeit finicky) way to do this, so you can do true forwarding of emails as attachments, headers-and-all (and not just forwarding as PDFs, as suggested earlier in this thread)...  For reference, I'm using an iPhone XS Max on iOS 16.1.1.

In order to forward an email as attachment, you have to do the following:

1. Open a new email (this will be the mail to which you attach the other email).
   2.Minimise the new email (by dragging the email down towards the bottom of the screen until it minimises as a Draft email)
2. Go to the folder containing the email you want to attach, and locate the mail in question (don't open it!)
3. Hold down on the email you want to attach, until it "pops out" of the folder and shows you a preview.
4. Keep your finger on the screen and drag down to the bottom of the screen.  When its at the bottom, all available draft emails will show.
   Move your finger onto the email you want to attach the email to, and hold until it maximises.
5. When your draft email maximises, lift your finger to drop the other email onto it as an attachment.

It can be a little awkward, and you might not do the exact finger moves first time - but it does work.

Comment: Isn't this the same as this old answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310567/237

Comment: Thank you @Dave! This worked a treat for attaching a recalcitrant email (which would not sync back to the IMAP server) as an EML file on an iPhone SE 3rd gen running iOS 17.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from 2/10/19 is almost right as of IOS 14.7.
This works but it is clumsy. Hey Apple fixit?

1. Click on the email you want to send as an attachment.
2. Click on the arrow at the bottom of the email and click the print option.
3. Hold your finger down on the picture of the email that shows up on the print screen until it pops up onto a new full sized screen.
4. Click on the “send to” button on the top right. From there you select the email icon which opens a new email with the original as an attachment as a PDF.
5. Fill in the Email send to address and subject and body.

Answer (score -2):

You can take a screenshot of the original email. This will save in Photos. You can then attach it to the new email.

Comment: The point of forwarding as an attachment is to get the *complete* email including all the headers   and other  bits that don't get included nw tha normal forward.  This is vital if you are trying to report problems with emails.

Answer (score -2):

I realize this question was posted in 2017 but considering it still shows up as a top result on Google I figured I’d provide an updated answer. You can now send an email as an attachment on the iPhone (at least I could on the iPhone X) although it was a little weird how I had to do it.

1) Click on the email you want to send as an attachment.
2) Click on the arrow at the bottom of the email and click the print option.
3) Hold your finger down on the picture of the email that shows up on the print screen until it pops up onto a new full sized screen.
4) Click on the “move to folder” button on the top right and from there you can select your email which will attach a copy of the email to a new email.

Comment: I cannot bring up the picture into full screen by holding my finger down on it. What iOS version were you on ? I am on 12.. almost last in 12 series.

Comment: That defeats the whole point of forwarding as an attachment. The reason you would want to forward as an attachment is to keep the original email in tact, including email headers. Printing the content is little more than a formatted email forward.