# How do you forward an email as an attachment of another email on an iPhone 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, attachments

How do you forward an email as an attachment of another email on an iPhone 7?

Comment: iOS version would be good info, in case something changed! Also, add tags when you're at it, like [tag:attachments], [tag:mail] etc., using [edit]

Comment: There is an answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351028/313842 on the linked question that claims to do the required, using print feature. I commented by failure there too.

Comment: The only way i could figure out is to save the email as a pdf and then attach the pdf to another email.